# How to get the list of options of a linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, module, kernel

For example, there is a `max_loop` option for the `loop` module.

Generally, how can I know what options are supported by a kernel module? Or, where can I find the list, should I dive into the source codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt` in the kernel documentation will give you many of them, and any in modules can be gleaned from `modinfo`.

```
# modinfo radeon
 ...
parm:           no_wb:Disable AGP writeback for scratch registers (int)
parm:           modeset:Disable/Enable modesetting (int)
parm:           dynclks:Disable/Enable dynamic clocks (int)
parm:           r4xx_atom:Enable ATOMBIOS modesetting for R4xx (int)
parm:           vramlimit:Restrict VRAM for testing (int)
parm:           agpmode:AGP Mode (-1 == PCI) (int)
parm:           gartsize:Size of PCIE/IGP gart to setup in megabytes (32,64, etc) (int)
parm:           benchmark:Run benchmark (int)
parm:           test:Run tests (int)
parm:           connector_table:Force connector table (int)
parm:           tv:TV enable (0 = disable) (int)
parm:           new_pll:Select new PLL code (int)
parm:           audio:Audio enable (0 = disable) (int)
parm:           disp_priority:Display Priority (0 = auto, 1 = normal, 2 = high) (int)
parm:           hw_i2c:hw i2c engine enable (0 = disable) (int)
parm:           pm:enable power management (0 = disable) (int)
```